# AJAX - Problem with real time CSS styling

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, dom

I have an HTML file which generates a list of DB-entries in a table by using PHP. That list is row-identifyed by using JS-DOM and making a XMLHttpRequest to my PHP backend. 
There I decide which color would be as response. When it was responded the color is set by

```
if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {                                         
    document.getElementById("artikel' . $row['id'] . '").style.color = this.responseText;                                                    
}
```

### The problem is:

The color is only set/changed correctly when

1) I am refreshing the page -> cause of a new DB entry in the PHP-Backend at AJAX

2) I make at least 2 klicks on it

What's the problem?

### This is the code that generates the entries

```html
<?php
foreach ($dataOfDBselect as $row) {

$color = "";
if ($row['status'] == "false") {
    $color = "#130f40";
} else {
    $color = "#badc58";
}

echo '<tbody class="table-text-small" id="artikel' . $row['id'] . '" style="color: ' . $color . ';">
<th class="text-table table-inner-big">' . $row['name'] . '</th>
<th class="table-inner-big text-table">' . $row['amount'] . '</th>

<th class="table-inner-big text-table"><i class="far fa-check-square" id="checkArtikel_' . $row['id'] . '"></i></th>
</tbody>
<script>
    document.getElementById("artikel' . $row['id'] . '").addEventListener("click", function () {
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "./core/handler_ArtikelChecked.php?f_identify=' . $row['id'] . '");

        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById("artikel' . $row['id'] . '").style.color = this.responseText;                                                    
            }
        };
        request.send();

    });
</script>';
}
?>
```

and this is what my PHP-Backend returns correctly to my site

`echo $toColor;` which is somethin like `$toColor = "#badc58";`

Comment: Perhaps can you share the full method? We do not know what `$row['id']` refers to. Perhaps can you track how is valued the `this.responseText` in the console or via an alert.  Perhaps you can also check if `"artikel' . $row['id'] . '"`  is really what you expect (this looks strange to me)

Comment: '$row['id']' is the DB-entry ID to define exactly what dataset was used and clicked.  'this.responseText' gets it´s response as String like '#badc58' and the color is correctly on my site as a response

Comment: so what I think is that the colorsetting by using ```.style.color``` is the problem cause when I set the text to something like a heading I get the correct color value from my response.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing Javascript and PHP together. Your if statement is Javascript, but in `document.getElementById("artikel' . $row['id'] . '").style.color = this.responseText;` you are trying to concatenate the id with value `$row['id']` that is defined some where in your php script?

Comment: Jep, thats exactly what I want cause this references are made by a PHP for.

Comment: Oh I see your updated question with your full script now. Thanks. Can you check the browser developer console to see if you are getting any errors?